# Is it possible to use EF CodeFirst on shared hosting? Specifically initializers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, shared-hosting, code-first, ef-code-first

I just bought 2 months of godaddy hosting.  I've written an ASP.NET MVC3 application using EF CodeFirst.  In the application I am using an initializer that will drop/create the database if the model has been changed.  I get an error when I try to do this saying

```
"Cannot drop the database 'cellularautomata', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."
```

I assume this has to do with the fact that I am on shared hosting and do not have permissions to drop/create databases.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GoDaddy allows you to use some command line tools for SOME database operations.  But with GoDaddy hosting, you cannot drop/create a database.

Use the Code First approach locally, create the database, then make scripts from that and run them on your GoDaddy database.